# How i get current product name by product collection?

Tags: magento2, product

How i get current product name in sendEmail funtion

```
if (isset($result) && $result) {
                $this->emailHelper->sendEmail('Product', $productName);
            }
```

And this is my full code.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace custommodule\ScheduleContentNotifier\Plugin;

use Magento\CatalogStaging\Model\ProductApplier;
use custommodule\ScheduleContentNotifier\Helper\Email;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\Staging\Api\UpdateRepositoryInterface;

class PluginProductApplier
{
    protected $emailHelper;
    protected $product; 
    /**
     * @var UpdateRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $updateRepository;

    /**
     * @var Collection
     */
    protected $productCollectionResource;

    /**
     * @param UpdateRepositoryInterface $updateRepository
     * @param Collection $productResource
     * @param ReindexPool $indexerPool
     * @param IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry
     */

    public function __construct(
        Collection $productResource,
        UpdateRepositoryInterface $updateRepository,
        Email $emailHelper,
    ) {
        $this->updateRepository = $updateRepository;
        $this->productCollectionResource = $productResource;
        $this->emailHelper = $emailHelper;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function aroundExecute(
        ProductApplier $subject,
        callable $proceed,
        array $entityIds
    ) {
        if ($entityIds) {
            $currentVersionId = $this->updateRepository->getVersionMaxIdByTime(
                strtotime("now")
            );
           $select = $this->productCollectionResource->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE)->columns(['entity_id', ])
                ->joinLeft(['ss' => 'staging_update'], 'e.created_in = ss.id', [])
                ->where('e.entity_id IN (?)', $entityIds)
                ->where('e.created_in =?', $currentVersionId)
                ->where('ss.is_rollback IS NULL');
            $result = $this->productCollectionResource
                ->getConnection()
                ->fetchAll($select);
            if (isset($result) && $result) {
                $this->emailHelper->sendEmail();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In your code, the $productName variable is not defined or assigned a value. To get the current product name.

```
 if (isset($result) && $result) {
    foreach ($result as $productData) {
        $productId = $productData['entity_id'];
        $product = $this->product->create()->load($productId);
        $productName = $product->getName();
        $this->emailHelper->sendEmail('Product', $productName);
    }
}
```

Here's the updated code snippet:

```
  <?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace custommodule\ScheduleContentNotifier\Plugin;

use Magento\CatalogStaging\Model\ProductApplier;
use custommodule\ScheduleContentNotifier\Helper\Email;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\Staging\Api\UpdateRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;

class PluginProductApplier
{
    protected $emailHelper;
    protected $product;
    /**
     * @var UpdateRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $updateRepository;

    /**
     * @var Collection
     */
    protected $productCollectionResource;

    /**
     * @param UpdateRepositoryInterface $updateRepository
     * @param Collection $productResource
     * @param ReindexPool $indexerPool
     * @param IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry
     */

    public function __construct(
        Collection $productResource,
        UpdateRepositoryInterface $updateRepository,
        Email $emailHelper,
        ProductFactory $product
    ) {
        $this->updateRepository = $updateRepository;
        $this->productCollectionResource = $productResource;
        $this->emailHelper = $emailHelper;
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function aroundExecute(
        ProductApplier $subject,
        callable $proceed,
        array $entityIds
    ) {
        if ($entityIds) {
            $currentVersionId = $this->updateRepository->getVersionMaxIdByTime(
                strtotime("now")
            );
            $select = $this->productCollectionResource->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE)->columns(['entity_id', ])
                ->joinLeft(['ss' => 'staging_update'], 'e.created_in = ss.id', [])
                ->where('e.entity_id IN (?)', $entityIds)
                ->where('e.created_in =?', $currentVersionId)
                ->where('ss.is_rollback IS NULL');
            $result = $this->productCollectionResource
                ->getConnection()
                ->fetchAll($select);
            if (isset($result) && $result) {
                foreach ($result as $productData) {
                    $productId = $productData['entity_id'];
                    $product = $this->product->create()->load($productId);
                    $productName = $product->getName();
                    $this->emailHelper->sendEmail('Product', $productName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This updated code will load each product using the product ID obtained from the result set and retrieve the product name using **$product->getName()**. Then it will pass the product name to the **sendEmail** method.

Answer (score 0):

**Get current product**

Using Object Manager

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
$name =  $product->getName();
var_dump($name);
```

Using construct

```
protected $registry;

public function __construct(
    
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    
)
{
    $this->registry = $registry;
   
}


public function getCurrentProduct()
{
    $product = $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    $name =  $product->getName();
    var_dump($name);
}
```